# Integrate SIP.js with React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, sip, jssip

Is there a way to integrate [SIP.js](http://www.sipjs.com) (both audio and video calling are needed) with React Native? Importing the library itself is easy enough, but the issues I'm running into are:

- WebRTC support: instead of using the browser's WebRTC functionality (which isn't present in a react native app), I included [react-native-webrtc](https://github.com/oney/react-native-webrtc), and modified SIP.js source code to use those. I got past WebRTC support errors, but I don't know if it actually works, because of the following issue.
- Attaching media: SIP.js expects to attach the call audio and video to `<audio>` and `<video>` elements in the browser (https://sipjs.com/guides/attach-media). Is there an existing implementation of a bridge or similar solution to use react native components with SIP.js call media?

Comment: Have you find a solution. I am facing a similar problem?

Comment: @Shubham1164 Unfortunately not. I'm currently using this React Native PJSIP module, but it is far from perfect: https://github.com/datso/react-native-pjsip.

Comment: According to this thread ( https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sip_js/ZUP0FEZpz44/O8UoLAMtAgAJ ), a custom SIP.js session description handler would need to be created for React Native.

Comment: Did you find any solution yet? I have also made a webphone in jssip library and now looking for android and ios app to use jssip or sip.js . If you have any success, please respond.

Comment: @Anup_Tripathi Unfortunately not. If mobile web is an option for you, then according to the SIP.js FAQ, SIP.js does support the latest version of Safari on iOS and Chrome on Android. https://sipjs.com/faq/

Comment: @penguinrob, After many research, I think I should wrap my code in Cordova to make Mobile Webphone. You can also try Cordova and share your findings.

Comment: Guys this repo is awesome I could connect my React Native app to the asterisk server via pjsip with this repo ...try the examples and see the magic 
https://github.com/telefon-one/react-native-sip2